# Bitbake recipe, copy in raw mode of huge set of different files

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I have a huge set of files that I want to raw copy in my rootfs. However, do_rootfs always tries to compile / install some files not in raw mode but checking their dependencies (and therefore fails with no package provides /usr/local/bin/...).

I just want to copy executable and other sort of files in raw mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more details here, like what exactly does it mean that "do_rootfs always tries to compile / install some files not in raw mode but checking their dependencies". Nothing in Yocto should compile code unless a recipe asks for it...

Answer (score 0):

As @jku pointed out, more details would be helpful.  From the limited information using the following in your layer:

```
do_configure[noexec] = "1"
do_compile[noexec] = "1"
do_install[noexec] = "1"
```

Will do exactly what the name suggests; will not execute the particular function such as configuring, compiling or installing on the required object.